# How to stop Eclipse / Scala IDE from uploading all my projects at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, scala, workflow

[EDIT]: I dont have a git console installed and therefore only use the git-plugin for eclipse.

I have several projects in my Eclipse / Scala IDE like this:

- project 1
- project 2
- project 3
- ...

It can happen that I work on i.e. project 1 and do some changes. After that I work on project 2 and also create changes. BUT project 2 is still faulty, as I have not finished changing all the code and want to go to bed or something like this.

Now I click on `project 1 -> team -> commit` ... and down in the file-window everything I have done pops up (project 1 - which I want to upload, and project 2 - which is faulty and which I dont want to upload).

I am aware that there is a filter, where you can type in text and by this only upload the stuff from project 1, but I have to type everytime. What if I forget to use the filter? I upload faulty code!

Also the filter is very primitive, as I cant even save templates to later just click on, I have to type the correct(!) filter-text everytime I want to commit.

So is there a way to only like click on a project and just upload that? Or keep other projects from being uploaded until they are ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is good practice to select which files you wanted to commit.

you can do this using command line using `git add <file-name>` then do `git commit`. I think eclipse also provides some kind of window for selecting files before commit.

Comment: Hm, I should have mentioned that I dont have a git console installed, I only use the git-plugin from eclipse. Will edit my post

Comment: I think git plugin does have commit dialog, which will ask you to select which files you wanted to commit. you can check this link for more info http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Committing_using_Commit_Dialog

Comment: This is indeed the dialog which I was mentioning in my post. The pictures seems outdated, because I also have s filter-line, where you can enter filter words. 

But again, this dialog is very primitive, what happens if you forget / misclick the files you want to upload? Also you have to type in the words and cant save the filters for later use.

Comment: let me clarify one thing. is project1 and project2 are in same git repository?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed in the same repository.

Comment: As per "my knowledge" you cant automate. If you have command line access you can simply go to `project` directory and enter `git add .` which will add all (changed) files in that path.